# Theory of Computation - Intersection of 2 Languages

Tags: regular-language, intersection-theory

Let's say that L1 is regular and that L1∩L2 is regular as well.

What L2 can be?Is the only option regular?
I have ruled out CF due to a theorem that says CF intersection Regular = Regular.

Furthermore,is it even worth trying to find a solution via the Venn diagram?Because I find odd that the union of 2 CF can be regular.

Comment: $L1$ could be the empty language (or any finite language).  Then $L2$ can be arbitrary, even non-computable, but both $L1$ and $L1 \cap L2$ are regular.

Comment: What theorem are you referring to that rules out CF?  If you "rule out CF" as a possibility for L2 then it sounds like you are saying it is impossible for L2 to be CF, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Your question appears to be "What can L2 be?".  But everything that you describe it sounds like "What is the least restrictive assumption on L2 that ensures that the intersection is regular?", which is a very different question.  So either you don't understand your own question or you are asking the wrong question.  Do you perhaps mean "What is the class of languages which have a regular intersection with every regular language?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If L1 is defined on even length strings, and L2 is defined to include all even-length strings, and an arbitrary subset of the odd-length strings, then if L1 is regular, L1 $\cap$ L2 $=$ L1 has to be regular, but L2 can be arbitrary.

Comment: Arbitrary in a way that it can be in any category? (CF,inumerable recursive etc?)

Comment: @AlexF. Yes, in any category.  It doesn't even need to be recursively enumerable.

Comment: So it can be CF as well.However that's against the theorem https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18642/intersection-of-context-free-with-regular-languages
EDIT : I hope that it's clear that I state that the L1intersectionL2 is regular and not the L2 is regular.

Comment: @AlexF.  The theorem you link to says that the intersection of a CF language and a regular language is CF.  In no way does it claim that it can never be regular, so I don't see how that is in any way related to your question.  Perhaps you need to clarify the quantifiers on L1 and L2.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.I interpreted it wrong and was failing to understand the answer.